# std::bad_alloc error in while loop

Tags: c++

Noob here. I know I'm not supposed to post homework, but I have no idea what could possibly be causing this issue. For some reason this while loop throws a std::bad_alloc exception just before it exits (ie when it reads end of file). It's only using 500 MB of RAM on a system with 8GB, so I'm pretty sure it's not overuse of memory. If someone could help, that would be great, because I've been searching for this issue for about four hours now and can't find a fix. It's probably something stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the code:

```
temperatures_in >> low >> high;
tempMin=low;
tempMax=high;
getLocation(temperatures_in, location);

while(!temperatures_in.eof()){
    temperatures_out << left << setw(20) << location;
    temperatures_out << right << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << setw(6) << low << setw(6) << high << endl;
    temperatures_in >> low >> high;
    getLocation(temperatures_in, location);
    if(low<tempMin){
        tempMin=low;
    }
    if(high>tempMax){
        tempMax=high;
    }
    cout << low << " " << tempMin << " " << high << " " << tempMax << " " << location;
}
```

Also, when I ran a debugger, it showed the exception somehow being thrown at line -1 (is that even possible?), even though I've tested outputs inside and outside the loop and it will execute code before the end of the loop, but not after.

Edit: Here's the getLocation() function:

```
void getLocation(ifstream &temperatures_in, string &location){
    char a;
    temperatures_in.get(a);
    while(a==' '){
        temperatures_in.get(a);
    }
    location="";
    while(a!='\n'){
        location+=a;
        temperatures_in.get(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: `bad_alloc` is typically thrown by `new` when it fails to allocate the requested memory. Where do you allocate memory?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the code you haven't posted, what happens in `getLocation()` for example?

Comment: `while(!some_input_stream.eof())` is always wrong.  There exist other reasons for a read to fail.  The stream returned by `getline` or `operator >>` can be implicitly converted to a boolean, which can be checked by your loop.  As for your problem, as KingsIndian said, `std::bad_alloc` is probably being thrown by `new`, so when it is thrown, use your debugger to inspect the call stack.

Comment: Don't use `eof()`. It's never correct.